# Showing server time not client time on the browser

Tags: javascript, meteor, momentjs

Actually im working with moment.js and showing weeks days on client side, i have this code (im using meteor),

```
Template.main.helpers({
  'showLunes' : function(){
  moment.locale("es");
    var lunes = moment().startOf('week').add(0,'days').format('LLLL');
  return lunes;
});
```

and calling this helper simply like `{{showLunes}}`

This works for me, but when other partner open the web page and he have different hour or date or whatever, the browser take client time and instead show current day, its show another day

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checkout `mizzao:timesync` package in atmospherejs.

This will give you the server side time

`TimeSync.serverTime()` will give you the server time and also it is reactive.

I'm using like below in my app to show minutes:seconds

`

```
var stime= TimeSync.serverTime();

var da=new Date(stime);

var rest= da.getMinutes()+":"+da.getSeconds();

return rest;
```

`
This helper returns the server time